# Retrieve list of ids by comparing total -vs- specified status

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a list of clients. Each client can have several activities (0..*). Each activity contains a status `is_completed` which is a Boolean (True/False).

I need to retrieve the list of clients that have all activities  completed:

- if a client has all its activities completed, I keep him.
- if a client has not all its activities completes, I ignore him.

I wrote an SQL query that does the job but I am not convinced that it is optimized:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.client_id
FROM clients_clientactivity AS cc
LEFT JOIN clients_client AS c ON (c.id = cc.client_id)
WHERE c.client_type_id = 2 
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(cc1.id) FROM clients_clientactivity AS cc1 WHERE cc1.client_id = cc.client_id
) = (
    SELECT COUNT(cc2.id) FROM clients_clientactivity AS cc2 WHERE cc2.is_completed = True AND cc2.client_id = cc.client_id
);
```

How can I improve it ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a not in select for the not true

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.client_id
FROM clients_clientactivity AS cc
LEFT JOIN clients_client AS c ON (c.id = cc.client_id)
WHERE c.client_type_id = 2 
AND cc.client_id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT cc2.client_id   
  FROM clients_clientactivity AS cc2 
  WHERE cc2.is_completed != True 
)
```

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge for your answer. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM clients_clientactivity ca JOIN
     clients_client c
     ON c.id = ca.client_id
WHERE c.client_type_id = 2 
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(ca.iscompleted)
```

Your `WHERE` clause converts the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, so I removed the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your time and your answer. I have compared your query with scaisedge's and yours is a little slower (~60ms compared to ~30ms). So I have accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify even further:

```
SELECT client_id
    FROM clients_clientactivity
    WHERE MIN(is_completed) = TRUE
    GROUP BY client_id
```

(TRUE==1, FALSE==0)

Subqueries are often slow.  `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is really bad (unless the optimizer has magically gotten smarter).

You did not explain how `client_type_id = 2`, but maybe something like:
clients_client

```
SELECT a.client_id
    FROM clients_client AS c
    JOIN clients_clientactivity AS a  ON (c.id = a.client_id)
    WHERE MIN(a.is_completed) = TRUE
      AND c.client_type_id = 2
    GROUP BY a.client_id
```

If performance is a problem, then:
`c` needs `INDEX(client_type_id, id)`
`a` needs `INDEX(client_id, is_completed)`